# make a matrix from counted co-occurrences

Tags: r

I have a dataset in which a single observation is made several times (I've also seen it called a "pile list") and the frequency for the combination is given. Here is an example:

```
colours <- structure(list(count = c(1L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 
1L), colour_1 = c("col 2", "col 7", "col 2", "col 6", "col 8", 
"col 6", "col 6", "col 6", "col 7", "col 6"), colour_2 = c("col 4", 
"col 4", "col 7", "col 2", "col 2", "col 7", "col 4", "col 6", 
"col 4", "col 8"), colour_3 = c("col 2", "col 1", "col 1", "col 2", 
"col 8", "col 8", "col 2", "col 1", "col 4", "col 3"), colour_4 = c("col 5", 
"col 6", "col 6", "col 2", "col 4", "col 2", "col 7", "col 8", 
"col 3", "col 2")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to find out how often a combination of any two observations (e.g. col 1 and col 2) has been counted, and to display this in a symmetrical matrix.

With two columns, it is not too difficult:

```
colours %>% 
  select(count, colour_1, colour_2) %>% 
  group_by(colour_1, colour_2) %>% 
  summarise(n = sum(count)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = colour_2, values_from = n)
```

But it is harder to do it far all combinations of all columns. We would have to, I think, construct the matrix first and then populate it with the values.

So let's construct the matrix:

```
# get all values for matrix
vals <- na.omit(unique(unlist(colours[, -1])))

p <- length(vals) #count how many values

#make the matrix
mtx <- matrix(data = 0L, nrow = p, ncol = p) #construct the matrix of the right size and populate with 0
dimnames(mtx) <- list(vals, vals) # apply labels
```

Now comes the part where I'm stuck: how to populate the matrix. Being a newbie at iterations, I think I might need nested loops, one running along all possible combinations of columns in `colours` and one running along all possible combinations of factors in `vals`.

```
var.combs <- combn(colnames(x), 2, simplify = TRUE) #get all combinations of data columns
val.combs <- combn(vals, 2, simplify = TRUE) # get all combinations of values
```

This is an example of how the loops could get to the values they need for the matrix:

```
sum <- colours %>% 
  select(count, colour_1, colour_2) %>% 
  filter(colour_1== "col 2", colour_2 == "col 5") %>%
  pull(count) %>% 
  sum
```

And if we iterate this over another combination, we can bring them together

```
sum2 <- colours %>% 
  select(count, colour_1, colour_3) %>% 
  filter(colour_1== "col 2", colour_3 == "col 5") %>%
  pull(count) %>% 
  sum

sums <- sum + sum2
```

The sum of all of these iterations is what we want in our matrix cell between col 2 and col 5.

```
mtx["col 2", "col 5"] <- mtx["col 5", "col 2"] <- sums # assign value to matrix.
```

So here is how I have tried to build the nested loops, but it is the first time I have tried this and it isn't working. Where am I going wrong?

```
var.pair <- seq_len(ncol(var.combs)) # set length of loops 
val.pair <- seq_len(ncol(val.combs))

for (i in var.pair){
    k <- var.combs[1, i] #select from first row of combinations
    l <- var.combs[2, i] #select from second row
    
    x <- colours %>% 
      select(count, k, l) #subset data columns
    
  for(j in val.pair){  
    m <- val.combs[1, i] #select from first row of combinations
    n <- val.combs[2, i] #select from second row of combinations
    
    y <- vector("double", length(var.combs))
    
    y[j] <- x %>% 
      filter(k == m, l == n) %>% # subset value pair
      pull(count) %>% # make vector from count
      sum()           # sum counts
  }
    
    
    z <- sum(y) # take a sum of the counts from each variable iteration
    
    mtx[m, n] <- mtx[n, m] <- z[i] # assign value to matrix. 
}
```

Comment: There shouldn't be a need to resot to loops, but I'm confused by your sample data: in every row, all four `colour_x` columns contain the same value.  I don't see where the "combinations" would come from.  As far as I can see, your input would simply produce a diagonal matrix, and I don't understand why the same value is repeated across all columns.  Can you post the output you expect from your input, please?

Comment: Yes, the question is not clear to me as well and having expected output would help clarify.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake there. I have now updated the dataset, does this make it clearer?